# Need to link my drop down option with a table in my database, once it's been selected

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I'm having some trouble with one drop down menu in my form called  Select Competition, I need the names of these competitions to link in with my competition ID which I hold in a table seen below. Essentially I need to take the user inputs from the dropdown menu Category, , the user input from where they type their Member ID in and the Image Title in and place them into my database tables.

[image: Screenshot of Database]

```
<div class="row"> <!--Below I have again used the foldy grids with image tags that link to a waiting page -->
                        <div class="grid-2">
                        <p><b>Upload photo entries here!</b></p>
                        <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <label>Select Competition</label>
                            <select name="Select Competition">
                            <option value="Default">Default</option>
                            <option value="1">Winter Warmer</option>
                            <option value="2">Fresh New Year</option>
                            <option value="3">Month of Love</option>
                            <option value="4">Seaside Scenery</option>
                            </select>
                        </fieldset>

                        <label>Enter Member ID</label>
                            <input type ="text" name ="member-id" placeholder="Enter Your Member ID...">
                            <label>Enter Title</label> 
                            <input type ="text" name ="img-title" placeholder="Enter Title...">
                          <table width="300" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="box">
                            <tr> 
                              <td width="246">
                                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000"> <!-- 2 Megabytes -->
                                <input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile"> 
                              </td>
                              <td width="80">
                                <input name="upload" type="submit" id="upload" value="Upload "> <!-- A button -->
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </form>

                        <?php
                        $uploadDir = 'images/';


                        if(isset($_POST['upload']))
                        {
                          $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                          $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
                          $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
                          $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
                          $memberID = $_POST['member-id'];
                          $imgTitle = $_POST['img-title'];
                          $catID = $_POST['catID'];

                          $filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;

                          $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);

                          if (!$result) {
                            echo "Error uploading file";
                    exit;
                  }

                  echo "<br>Files uploaded<br>";

                if(mysqli_connect_errno())
                {
                  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                    exit();
                }

                if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
                {
                $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
                $filePath = addslashes($filePath);
                } 


                $query = "INSERT INTO `tblImage` (`fldImageID`, `fldMemberID`, `fldCatID`, `fldFilePath`, `fldName`) VALUES (NULL, '$memberID', '$catID', '$filePath', '$imgTitle')";

                // echo $query;
                $result = $conn->query($query) or die ("error");

                }

                  ?>
                </div>
```

The error appearing on the screen is:

[image: Error on the html page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably use `<select name="catID">`

Something like this:

```
<select name="catID">
  <option value="">Select Competition</option>
  <option value="Default">Default</option>
  <option value="1">Winter Warmer</option>
  <option value="2">Fresh New Year</option>
  <option value="3">Month of Love</option>
  <option value="4">Seaside Scenery</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That was a stupid mistake on my behalf, thank you so so much @AnuragSrivastava